# using background-size cover with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm using a background image which should cover the hole body area. Furthermore I want a sticky footer at the bottom. Now my main problem is that the background-image stops after the 100% of the body-element (after scrolling). But the background-image should cover the hole area - I could say it should have the width of the body (not just of the content which has not the hole width and is centered) and the height of the content which may be more than 100% of the browser height.

I tried the following code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <div id="backgroundWrapper">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <header>
                    ...
                </header>
                <article>
                    ...
                </article>
                <footer>
                    ...
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    div#backgroundWrapper {
        min-height: 100%;

        background: url('/images/bodyBackground.jpg') no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    div#backgroundWrapper > div#wrapper {
        position: relative;

        width: 1024px;
        min-height: 100%;

        margin: 0 auto;
    }

div#wrapper > footer {
        position: absolute;

        width: 100%;
        height: 115px;

        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Although I gave min-height: 100% to the background wrapper, the inner wrapper which also has min-height: 100% doesn't fit the height (because its positioning is relative), so the sticky footer is not at the window bottom if the content is small.

Can you help me?
Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfd2d/

**EDIT**: It is possible if I move the footer after the inner wrapper so that it's a direct child of the background wrapper but it would be nice if the footer is child of the inner wrapper because I haven't to give it the wrapper with and center it again.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and link it?